# Making and storing different variables in python with user input

Tags: python

I have a problem where i have to take input on a number and depending on that number ask the user a question x many times and store the info in variables that will be output later EG:

ask user how many x they need

```
for i in range(x)
  what is the number {} player name ? .format(i)
  i += 1
```

print out stuff like :

```
names :
john - 1 
max - 2
etc - 3
```

Comment: Your second paragraph is not proper english, I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: second paragraph ? you mean print out stuff like ? ok ill explain it, i mean that after i get input and store the variables in the end i will be able to print them out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program may look something like this :-

```
lsNames = []
print "How many players do you have ?"
iPlayers = raw_input()

for i in range(int(iPlayers)):
    playerName = raw_input("Enter  {} player name".format(i + 1))
    lsNames.append(playerName)

print ",".join(lsNames)
```

Comment: i will look into your answer when i have the time, i am unable to test what you gave me at the moment but thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not an issue @Taka

Answer (score 0):

```
answers = {} # an answers dictionary
for i in range(x): # note the trailing : needed for a loop
    question = "what is the number {} player name ?".format(i)
    name = input(question)
    answers[i] = name
```

Note, in python 2, you want `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Later, something like-

```
for key in answers:
    print('player {} is {}'.format(key, answers[key])
```